# Contact us page cannot be edited/replaced with extension

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I would like to display a static block on my contact us page, so I m adding to form.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('static-block')->toHtml(); ?>
```

while this works like a charm on my localhost and on another test site, it is not working on my live site: http://lemon-pharma.es/contacts

So I tried to install a contact us extension to do that job: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ultimate-contact-us-page-1.html

With the same result. I have all the extension menu options in the admin, but the frontend just does not display this extension (and again, no issues on localhost and another test site). It is now enabled on lemon-pharm link above.

I notice though that when I disable this extension, the compare products/callout is displayed in the right column, when I enable the extension, the right column disappears.

After doing tons of research, I worked with the compiler, I cleared it, reindexed and enabled again, but no success. I also made all folders 755 and files 644 so that should be fine. Also cleared the cache, etc before and after each change.

Can anyone point me into a direction here?

Comment: Look for some upcase issue. Normally Linux based servers stop working things programed on Windows becouse Linux is case sensitive and windows not.

Comment: thanks Guerra, I found the problem.. there was already another extension called 'contactsformcaptcha' which totally ruined my afternoon. ;) seems so obvious now.